# Error 1072: Key Column `course_id` does not exist

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to make a simple table with foreign keys but it seems there's a problem with the id. I've tried everything but still comes up with an error message please help. Thanks.

```
CREATE TABLE `staff_info`(
`staff_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`first_name`      VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`last_name`       VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`office_add`      VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`email`           INT NULL,
`changed`         TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`staff_id`),
FOREIGN KEY(`course_id`) 
REFERENCES `course_info`(`course_id`)
 )
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `course_info`(
`course_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`name`      VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`module`    VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`StartDate` TIMESTAMP,
`EndDate`   TIMESTAMP,  
`course_Update` TIMESTAMP,

PRIMARY KEY(`course_id`),
FOREIGN KEY(`student_id`)
REFERENCES student(`student_id`)
)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `student` (
`student_id`    INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`first_name`    VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`end_name`      VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`gender`        VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,   
`email`         VARCHAR(25) NULL,
`phone`         VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
`student_update`TIMESTAMP,

PRIMARY KEY(`student_id`)
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table destruct and creation orders are invalid

```
CREATE TABLE `student` (
`student_id`    INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`first_name`    VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`end_name`      VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`gender`        VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,   
`email`         VARCHAR(25) NULL,
`phone`         VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
`student_update`TIMESTAMP,

PRIMARY KEY(`student_id`)
);


CREATE TABLE `course_info`(
`course_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`student_id` INT, 
`name`      VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`module`    VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`StartDate` TIMESTAMP,
`EndDate`   TIMESTAMP,  
`course_Update` TIMESTAMP,

PRIMARY KEY(`course_id`),
FOREIGN KEY(`student_id`)
REFERENCES student(`student_id`)
)


CREATE TABLE `staff_info`(
`staff_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`course_id` INT,
`first_name`      VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`last_name`       VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`office_add`      VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`email`           INT NULL,
`changed`         TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`staff_id`),
FOREIGN KEY(`course_id`) 
REFERENCES `course_info`(`course_id`)
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

set `CREATE TABLE student` before `CREATE TABLE course_info`
you use `student_id` when does not exist `studen`,
and use `course_id` when does not exist `course`

Answer (score 0):

In your SQL Query for TABLE `student`, you are missing

```
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Because `course` table is creating `FOREIGN KEY` from table `student`.

Also you need to create tables in the order.

> 1. student
> 2. course_info
> 3. staff_info